# Collision Detection Between An Image And Rectangle In Pygame?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

So, I am trying to detect collision between my virus and rectangle, I have classes set up for each of them and I have the code for the collision, but the code ends up not working and I'm not sure what went wrong. I have turned the image into a rectangle and used colliderect to detect collision between the virus and the base, but nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated on why this is!

```
import pygame, random, time
pygame.init()

#Colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

#Screen Stuff
size = (1080, 640)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('Random Platformer')
icon = pygame.image.load('Icon.jpg')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
pygame.display.update()

#Misc Stuff
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

#Objects
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.player = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.rect = self.player.get_rect()
    def load(self):
        screen.blit(self.player, (self.x, self.y))
    def move_right(self):
        self.x += 7.5
    def move_left(self):
        self.x -= 7.5
    def move_up(self):
        self.y -= 7.5
    def move_down(self):
        self.y += 7.5

class Block:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, length, edge_thickness):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.length = length
        self.edge_thickness = edge_thickness
    def load(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, [self.x, self.y, 
        self.width, self.length], self.edge_thickness)

#Players
virus = Player(100, 539, 'Virus.jpg')

#Blocks
level_base = Block(0, 561, 1080, 80, 0)

#Game Loop
while running:
    #Level Generation
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    level_base.load()
    virus.load()

    if level_base.rect.colliderect(virus.rect):
        print ('Hi')

    #Controls
    key_press = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if key_press[pygame.K_d]:
        virus.move_right()
    if key_press[pygame.K_a]:
        virus.move_left()
    if key_press[pygame.K_w]:
        virus.move_up()
    if key_press[pygame.K_s]:
        virus.move_down()

    #Game Code
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            break

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the collision detection doesn't work, it helps to print the `rect`s of the involved objects each frame. You'll see that the rect of the `virus` is positioned at the topleft coords of the screen (0, 0) and never moves when the virus moves.

In the `__init__` method you have to set the coords of the `self.rect`, for example by passing x and y to get_rect as the `topleft` or `center` argument:

```
self.rect = self.player.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
```

You could also do this:

```
self.rect.x = x
self.rect.y = y
```

And when the player moves, you always have to update the rect as well. You could also do this in an `update` method.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.player = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.rect = self.player.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
    def load(self):
        screen.blit(self.player, self.rect)
    def move_right(self):
        self.x += 7.5
        self.rect.x = self.x
    def move_left(self):
        self.x -= 7.5
        self.rect.x = self.x
    def move_up(self):
        self.y -= 7.5
        self.rect.y = self.y
    def move_down(self):
        self.y += 7.5
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

Comment: Side note: I recommend loading images as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47883299/6220679).